# What is the largest abelian subgroup in $S_n$?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

I am almost to complete my first course in group theory.  I have read Dummit and Foote into chapter 5.
I know that I can always find an abelian subgroup isomorphic to $C_{k_1} \times C_{k_2} \times  ... \times C_{k_t}$ in $S_n$ where $n = k_1 + k_2 + ... + k_t$.  Specifically, the permutation group $G = <(1 \ 2\ ...\ k_1),(k_1+1 \ ...\ k_2),...,(n-k_t+1\ ...\ n)>$.

There are many ways to express an isomorphism type of an abelian group as a direct product of cyclic factors.  If I express the isomorphism type in its elementary divisor (primary) decomposition this seems to minimize $n$.  I am somewhat familiar with Landau's function (Sloane's A000793) which gives the maximal lcm over all the partitions of $n$.  I think that this sequence gives the answer to my question but there are no comments in the data base regarding this.  At any rate, I am unsure and would like some help on this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since all direct factors contribute, you don't need the lcm of the orders. Also note that $|C_2\times C_2\times\cdots\times C_2|$ ($k$ factors, on $2k$ points) has order $2^k\ge 2k$, so it is beneficial to split any cycle of length $>3$ into groups of $2$-cycles. I fact (as Derek Holt observed - $2^3<3^2$ on 6 points) splitting into 3-cycles gives an even larger order, but going to larger cycle lengths will produce worse results. 
This means that the largest subgroup is the direct product of copies of $C_3$ with $2$-cycles thrown in on the remaining points (i.e. if $n\equiv 0\pmod{3}$ there is no $2$-cycle, if it is $\equiv 2$ there is $1$ two cycle, and if it is $\equiv 1$ we remove one 3-cycle and write two $2$-cycles (or a $V_4$, or a 4-cycle, as $4=2^2$) on the 3 points plus the remaining point).

Comment: OK Thanks.  I see now that we don't need to consider the lcm of the orders (of course not, the order of the direct product group is the PRODUCT of the orders of its factors).  I computed (using Mathematica) the maximal product over the partitions of n to find Sloane's A000792.  A comment in that sequence states that this is indeed the answer to my question.  However this does not agree with your reply.  Consider S_6, which contains the subgroup of order 9, <(1 2 3) , (4 5 6)>.

Comment: Yes, $3^{n/3} > 2^{n/2}$ for large $n$, so you need to take mainly $3$-cycles, and just $1$ or $2$ $2$-cycles.

Comment: We could then ask how many distinct abelian subgroups of maximal order are contained in S_n.  I think these are enumerated by the exponential generating function, exp(x^3/3)*( 1 + exp(x^2/2 + x^2/2) + exp(x^4/4) ).

Comment: The generating function that I gave above is NOT correct.

Comment: I think that the number of abelian subgroups of maximal order in S_n for n=1,2,... is 1,1,1,6,10,10,210,280,280,12600,15400,... and is given by the e.g.f. exp(x^3/3!)*(1 + x^2/2 + x^4/4) + x - 1.    This sequence is not given in OEIS.  Can GAP verify these terms?

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer If $n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ there are 3 classes of groups (instead of $(1,2),(3,4)$ use $(1,2,3,4)$ or $(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4)$). Do you also want to count these, or (as your numbers do) only one class?

Comment: I think? that the numbers I give above count ALL such subgroups.  For example, if n =4 we have three cyclic groups:  <(1234)> = <(1432)>,  <(1243)> = <(1342)>,  <(1324)> = <(1423)> and three groups isomorphhic to C_2 X C_2:  <(12),(34)>, <(13),(24)>, <(14),(23)>  for a total of 6 distinct subgroups of order 4.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer You are missing $<(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(2,4)>$. I get (with GAP):   1, 1, 1, 7, 10, 10, 245, 280, 280, 14700 -- So I suspect you are missing a term for this $V_4$. (Still no OEIS entry even with the changes.)

Comment: @ Dr. Hulpke.  How many terms can you get with Gap?  I adjusted my e.g.f. and now I have:  1, 1, 1, 7, 10, 10, 245, 280, 280, 14700, 15400, 15400, 1401400,
1401400, 1401400, 196196000, 190590400, 190590400, 38022784800,
36212176000,...  Do you agree with this?

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Yes, I agree (with code that computes the normalizer indices of representatives of the maximal abelian subgroups without constructing the whole subgroup lattice). Next two would be another 36212176000 and then 9759181432000. Interesting enough at 20 the sequence is not monotonous at the first time.

Comment: @ Dr. Hulpke. The sequence is sufficiently interesting to be submitted to OEIS.  At your request I can make the submission, or not.  I can list yourself as co-author, or not.  I can add the e.g.f to the sequence if you are interested in submitting it yourself.  Thanks for helping me with this problem.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Please feel free to submit. There is no need to list me as co-author.